# Is this a link-only answer which should be improved by adding most important link content into answer?

Tags: discussion, answer-quality, hyperlinks

The question [How to prevent users from executing commands through browser URL](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/204459/44119) has an [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/204462/44119) which IMO does not provide the answer to the question, because the "how-to" information what was asked is present only in linked pages. Is it legitimate to ask the author to put the most important how-to information directly into the answer? The OP is obviously satisfied, but what about other readers?

In its current state, the answer has some information, but since the question literally starts with words "How to" and the answer contains no how-to information except of links, I found it insufficient from quality perspective. Do I understand the basic quality requirements expected from answers right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to post bare links when the link is to a tangent or to secondary information. No need to fill the answer with text that is only indirectly relevant.

If the link is meant to answer the main question, then the links should be quoted, else the meat of the answer is lost if the link dies.

In the answer you linked, there is no clear interpretation whether "and how do I prevent it?" is secondary or a main component to the question. The answer is treating it as secondary, which would mean that the bare links might be fine.

This is one of those toss-up situations that is up to interpretation. If the OP is satisfied, then it might be fine to leave it.